# Non-storage device in M.2 M-Key port not working, how to debug?

Tags: pci-express, adapter, usb-c, nvme, m.2

I've got an 51nb X210 Thinkpad with an M-keyed M.2 slot. My ultimate goal is to add a Thunderbolt 3 port via the GC-Titan Ridge card, but for now I want to start with a USB-C port. 
To that end, I got a [Sunix UPD2018](http://www.sunixusa.com/product/upd2018/#1502314231970-ae77249a-2088) (x1 PCIe) and several adapters ([mPCIe -> x1 PCIe](https://www.adt.link/product/R61.html) & [M.2 -> x4 PCIe](https://www.adt.link/product/R42.html)).

I confirmed that the Sunix card works if I connect it to my WiFi PCIe slot via the first mentioned adapter.

I also have a working M-keyed NVMe SSD (so, actual x4 PCIe works correctly).

However, anything I do to try getting the Sunix card working in the M.2 slot fails.

My question is: Do I need to do anything special in the BIOS to recognize non-storage devices in this slot? How can I tell which root port the slot is connected to?

Theoretically I should even be able to do an eGPU via this slot, right? So I really shouldn't have any trouble getting the Sunix card working...

Cheers,
Rafael

Comment: Who is the M2 Card Maker?  I do not have such a port in my own X230.  If not Lenovo, the BIOS may not recognize it.

Comment: This is the non-Lenovo 3rd-party mainboard mentioned by K7AAY below. So it also uses a custom AMI BIOS that has a TON of configurable options...

Comment: Does the custom BIOS show the M2 card?

Comment: It shows the NVME SSD in the NVME section, yes. When the NVME drive is connected, it also shows up in a PCI scan from whatever OS I boot (duh - an OS is installed on this disk when I have it installed).  But there's no way to list what's connected to each PCI root port in the BIOS separately. When I add the Sunix / non-storage cards, NVME drives obviously aren't listed in the BIOS, and nothing ever shows up on PCI scans once booted.

Comment: Possibly the modified BIOS is not compatible with the OS you booted from

Comment: No that's not what I meant. I can boot from the NVME drive without issues; it has an OS on it. When it's installed, it shows up in the BIOS in the NVME section. There is no way of viewing that same drive in the PCIe Root Port section - that part doesn't list devices at all.
If I boot either the OS on the NVME drive or one on a different drive, the NVME drive is visible during a PCI scan.
Anything else installed in the slot when an OS is booted from the non-NVME drive does not appear.

Comment: That's possible, but the ones I picked are the fancy ones which are specifically designed to preserve the signal integrity all the way up to 8GB/s, to avoid this exact issue. It's not like I'm seeing an unknown / corrupted device, which might be indicative of that issue...

Answer (score 0):

"*Theoretically I should even be able to do an eGPU via this slot, right?*"

No. The M.2 storage connector is not designed for eGPU expansion, even with the [third party replacement motherboard from LCDFans](https://liliputing.com/2018/03/x210-mod-turns-classic-lenovo-thinkpad-x201-into-a-modern-pc.html) installed to turn an Thinkpad X200 or X201 into a more modern machine.

Comment: I'm using that exact motherboard, yes.

What prevents it from doing so?

Comment: That's a question for LCDFans who built it.

Comment: That's my next step, yes. What makes you say that the slot can't be used for an eGPU, meanwhile?

Comment: Experience: Tried the same thing on several other ThinkPad models.